# Can it make the x509Certificate not expire? If so, how?<EOM>

Tags: security, x509certificate

Can it make the x509Certificate not expire? If so, how?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more than that.  Is this a cert you are creating or one provided from elsewhere?  In general, all certs must have an expiration date/time, but it can be very far into the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. But as long as you are generating your own X509 certs, you can make them expire a good distance in the future.

If you're purchasing a true X509 cert, you're going to have to pay to renew it every so many years (and there's no getting around that).